# Toolbars inside tabs

Tags: qt4, qtabwidget, toolbars

Is it possible to add a tool bar inside `QWidget` that is placed inside a tab (in `QTabWidget`) ?
The idea is to put a separate tool bar for each tab.

It seems that tool bars can only be placed inside `QMainWindow`.

Comment: It looks like I can insert into QTabWidget widgets that inherit from QMainWindow. It seems to work fine :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`QToolBar` is an ordinary `QWidget`, you can add it to a layout.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know that. Its a shame that QtCreator doesn't allow to add toolbars as widgets. At least not directly. I think I solved my problem by using QMainWindow widgets inside QTabWidget.