# How to add a QToolBar inside a QTabWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtabwidget, qtoolbar

I have been trying to add a `QToolBar` inside a `QTabWidget` in order to achieve something like the image below, so that everytime I add a new `QTabWidget` I have also a related `QToolBar` inside it.

[image: tab]

Everything seems to work fine, I create a `QAction` to link it to the `QTabWidget` and according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227889/toolbars-inside-tabs) it seems to be possible to do that but **the problem** is that when I compile nothing shows up as shows below:

[image: tab2]

Below is what I have done so far:

**mainwindow.h**

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    void onChangeTab(int index);
    void newTab();
    void closeTab(const int &index);
private slots:
    void on_addTabBtn_clicked();
    void on_tabWidget_tabCloseRequested(int index);
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QAction *addTab1;
    QToolBar *mToolBar1;
    QAction *addIconToolBar1;
};
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->tabWidget->clear();
    ui->tabWidget->setTabsClosable(true);
    ui->tabWidget->addTab(new QLabel("Add"), QString("Add"));
    ui->toolBar->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::ActionsContextMenu);

    mToolBar1 = new QToolBar;
    addIconToolBar1 = new QAction;
    addIconToolBar1->setIcon(QIcon("qrc:/cardio.png"));
    ui->toolBar->addWidget(mToolBar1);
    ui->toolBar->addAction(addIconToolBar1);

    connect(ui->addTabBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [&] { ui->tabWidget->addTab(new QLabel("Add"), QString("Add")); });
    connect(ui->tabWidget, SIGNAL(tabCloseRequested(int)), this, SLOT(closeTab(int)));

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_addTabBtn_clicked()
{
    int index = 0;
    if(index == this->ui->tabWidget->count() - 1) {
        newTab();
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_tabWidget_tabCloseRequested(int index)
{
    ui->tabWidget->removeTab(index);
}
```

I tried to solve the problem in many ways and researched what the cause might be. I came across several references such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227889/toolbars-inside-tabs), which is the most important I found as the user seems to be doing it but there is no reference to documentation or no example to code to understand/study through.

Thanks for pointing to the right direction to solve this issue.

Comment: You have to add a widget inside your tab, then add a Layout inside the widget and put your toolbar in the widget

Comment: @thibsc , thanks for stopping by and reading the question. Thanks for your suggestion. I will go ahead with that and get back to you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do something like this, and it really works.

```
QToolBar *toolbar=new QToolBar("toolbar",ui->tab);
toolbar->addAction("action1");
toolbar->addAction("action2");
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMQYp.png)

Comment: **I guess** the toolbar what you want does not be necessary to be draged. :)

Comment: Correct! :) I don't need the toolbar to be dragged anywhere but needs to be fixed. You example was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you are trying to add Toolbar to your TabWidget...
You must define Layout, add your toolbar to that layout and finally set layout to your tabWidget.

Try to do something like this, in your mainwindow constructor.

```
QHBoxLayout* tabWidgetLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
tabWidgetLayout->addWidget( your toolbar);
tabwidget->setLayout(tabWidgetLayout);
```

Also don't forget to include QHBoxLayout's header.

Even if other answers may seem to work, this is actually the right way to do what you asked for.